# Is it possible to bind an event against a menu instead of a menu item in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

Nothing to add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want an event when your menu is opened? Use `EVT_MENU_OPEN(func)` (`wxMenuEvent`). But it's not in particular precise. As the documentation says, it is only sent once if you open a menu. For another event you have to close it and open another menu again. I.e in between, you can open other menus (by hovering other items in the menubar), and the event won't be sent again.

What do you need this for? Probably there is another way to do it, instead of listening for this kind of event.

If you want an event for all items of a menu, use `EVT_MENU_RANGE(id1, id2, func)` (it's using `wxCommandEvent`). All IDs starting from `id1` up to and including `id2` will be connected to the given event handler. Using a range instead of connecting each item separate will provide for better performance, as there are fewer items in the event-handler list.

Comment: Thanks a bunch this helps-sometimes I struggle to read the documentation.